# React-router redirects to 404 when used with query params

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I need to change the address in browser when the user submits the search query, based on that query (something familiar to what Google does). When I do this, the address changes properly, but it redirects me to my *404 route*. And when I manually input text to the address bar, I can see the proper page.

This is a part of my routes:

```
...
<Route path="some-address" component={MyComponent}>
    <Route  path=":query" />
</Route>
...
```

Here's a **simplified** version of my component:

```
@withRouter
@connect(...)
export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={(e) => {
                e.preventDefault(); 
                this.props.router.push(e.target.myInput.value)}}
            >
                <input name="myInput" />
            </form>
    }
}
```

React Router is 2.6.1 version.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I managed to solve this:

```
    @withRouter
    @connect(...)
    export default class MyComponent extends Component {
        ...
        render() {
            return (
                <form onSubmit={(e) => {
                    e.preventDefault(); 
                    this.props.router.push({
                        pathname: this.props.location.pathname,
                        query: e.target.myInput.value && {search: e.target.myInput.value}
                    })
                }}>
                    <input name="myInput" />
                </form>
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this syntax :

```
<Route path="/some-address" component={MyComponent}>
    <Route  path=":query" />
</Route>
```